# Update localisation on the fly possible?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF app where i have multiple languages translated. I use resx files. Now when the customer has got software is there a way for me to build in in the application that it can retrieve new versions of the localisation or even new languages without sending new version ? I can see .NET converts the resx file to a dll, can that be done on the fly if so how ?

/donnib

Answer (score 1):

I usually implement localization with a [custom markup extension](https://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html), except I use the English text itself as the key, which makes it easier for the developers on my team to work with. I also [add my custom extension's namespace to the XAML default namespace](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and), which allows me to write code like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Translate 'Hello World!'}" />
```

It's then very easy to write a quick utility that scans your view folders for XAML files, extracts these keys and places them into a spreadsheet for the translators. In my case the translations that come back usually get wrapped up in XML files and embedded in the application itself for the markup extension to use at run-time.

Comment: thank you. I would like to use the resx files since i would like to use an external localization tool for our translators so they can translate using a webtool such as phraseapp and then the software can retrieve these texts from the cloud.

Comment: You can actually bind directly to res strings (I think you have to flag the file to generate global code or something), but you lose the ability to change locale on-the-fly. Check out the [wpflocalization project on codeplex](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wpflocalization), they show a couple of techniques that work around this without the need for a custom markup extension.